# ASP.net: Can I have 2 different versions of same dll/assembly in the bin folder?

Tags: asp.net, iis, dll

I am working on a large web application implemented in ASP.net. The main part of application, much of it implemented by a 3rd party, is managed by others so I don't have much control over it.

I have implemented 8 ASP.net custom controls which compile to separate DLLs and are put into the application's bin folder. These controls have to link to a couple of DLLs (or should that be assemblies?) from the main application which are also stored in the bin folder. Let's call them `MainAppCore1.dll` and `MainAppCore2.dll`. These seem to be managed .NET code.

My problem is that the main application has been updated, and worse looks like regularly being updated in the near future, due to to bugs problems I have compiled all my controls against the original version of the main app dlls, so now they won't load. Obviously I can solve the issue by recompiling all the controls against the new versions of `MainAppCore1.dll` and `MainAppCore2.dll` but am looking for a smarter way

My question is: is it possible to keep **2 versions** of the main app dlls in the bin folder so that my controls will keep working (probably) each time the main app is upgraded?

I don't want to have to edit the `web.config` file by the way as this would be politically complicated.

Comment: Is the main application in source control?

Comment: Good question: no it isn't! And I can't do anything about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shortly and Simply, **you cannot** . Broadly speaking having two versions of .net assemblies in a single folder is only possible in GAC(Global Assembly Cache) folder which is a special folder, where multiple versions of .Net assemblies can run and your control assemblies can point to specific version in GAC, regardless of how many versions exist in there. One possible solution is to ask your 3rd party vendors to strongly name their MainCore1.dll and install it in GAC, every time the version changes, and then in your web.config you can point to a particular version.

Comment: Are you sure it will work? I doubt because it will be the same namespace and the same classes...When in memory, how an executable can distinguish one from the other?

Answer (score 1):

Place your 8 custom controls in their own library project and reference that project from the main one. Presumably everything is in source control so there shouldn't be any versioning problems when you do a "Get latest".

Comment: Main application isn't in source control - or more most of it will be in 3rd party's source control. And I cannot ask them to link to my code as they are supplying a platform to sell to mulitiple clients.